# How to synchronize database in AX using powershell script?

Tags: powershell, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

I'm creating a script for AX deployment from one instance to another (stage to test instance). I would want to synchronize the database using just a powershell command.

Does anyone know how to synchronize the database using just a powershell command or AX management utility command?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

An extract from the [F.A.Q. for Dynamics AX](http://axfaq.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/ax2012-utils-its-all-about-scripting_22.html) blog:

```
$axProcess = Start-Process -PassThru ($axClientPath + "`\Ax32.exe") -ArgumentList ($params + " -StartupCmd=Synchronize")
if ($axProcess.WaitForExit($AXSYNCTIMEOUT) -eq $false)
{
    Throw ("Error: Synchronize did not complete within " + $AXSYNCTIMEOUT / 60000 + " minutes")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I've read that but I was hoping for a simpler approach. is there any other way? :-)

Comment: Does anyone know where to find the sync logs using this script?

Comment: Simpler option: `Synchronize-AXDatabase` (though still does the above in the background): https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/goshoom/archive/2011/12/13/dynamicsaxcommunity-powershell-module-introduction.  Related module has since been migrated to GitHub: https://github.com/jorisdg/dynamicsaxadmin

Comment: Regarding Log files, the default location is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\MicrosoftDynamicsAX\Log`; amend this path as appropriate for your instance (see Tommy Skaue's answer here: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/161960)